# Is AES vulnerable if the plain texts share a known format?

Tags: cryptography, aes

AES encryption, if done correctly (secure mode; random IVs for every text; ...) is considered secure. Does this change if the plain texts have well-known formats?

For instance, say we encrypt JSON strings that conform to a public schema. That is, the input strings all start off in the same way, say

```
{
    resourceId: <number>,
    ...
}
```

Is this a problem per se? Does it become a problem if the shared prefix is long, in particular longer than one AES block?

That would be 16 bytes in the case of Common Crypto, which is not a lot; above example has (at least) 15 bytes shared prefix even assuming ASCII encoding!

Comment: Knowing parts of the plaintext is a standard assumption in cryptography and all decent modes fullfil it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any modern encryption method is secure against known-plaintext attacks, and even chosen-plaintext attacks. The only thing that is exposed by a ciphertext is its (approximate) length. The mathematical notion behind this is [indistiguishability under chosen-plaintext attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#IND-CPA) (IND-CPA for short); what this means in a nutshell is that if an adversary chooses two plaintexts of equal length and receives the encryption of one of them, the adversary is unable to tell which one was encrypted. The two plaintexts may have a common prefix, they may differ by as little as one bit. Computer-era cryptographic algorithms are generally designed to be robust in terms of what data they can process — the inputs can be any set of byte strings (up to a very large length limit).

This assumes that the encryption is performed correctly, in particular with a valid mode (such as CTR or CBC, never EBC) and proper IV selection (random each time a message is encrypted is always fine).

Note that IND-CPA is not the full story. Some attacks may be possible where the adversary submits chosen ciphertexts (that may or may not be valid) to the party with the secret key. An adversary may be able to obtain information by submitting variations of a ciphertext (even if they don't know what it decrypts to), having them decrypted, and observing the consequences (even if they don't get access to the decrypted output, they may be able to observe how long it takes, whether it triggers certain errors, etc.). Many systems built on cryptography actually require [indistinguishability under adaptive chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_chosen-ciphertext_attack) (IND-CCA2). Protection against chosen ciphertext attacks requires authentication.

The best way to authenticate data, which protects against chosen ciphertext attacks, is to use an [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode. See [Why should I use Authenticated Encryption instead of just encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12178/why-should-i-use-authenticated-encryption-instead-of-just-encryption/12192#12192) for a more detailed explanation. Popular ones include [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), [CCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode), [OCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode) and [EAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode), [CWC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CWC_mode). Any of these five is as secure as it gets; see [Choice of authenticated encryption mode for whole messages](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18860/choice-of-authenticated-encryption-mode-for-whole-messages) for other considerations such as performance. If you have to use a library that doesn't provide AEAD modes, you can combine a MAC with CBC or CTR, but [doing it right is tricky](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac); in 2017, I think that if your library doesn't provide AEAD modes, you should get a more up-to-date library.

Comment: Side note: on Apple's platforms, Common Crypto does indeed not provide authenticated AES modes. :/